# Undefined reference - jQuery selector vs JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, undefined-reference

This is more of a general curiosity question.

I happen to have the following jQuery code snippet (similar to many I've written):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var light = document.getElementById('light');
    var black = document.getElementById('black_overlay');

    $('#galeria_popup').click(function() {
        light.style.display='block';
        black.style.display='block';
    });

    $('#black_overlay').click(function() {
        light.style.display='none';
        black.style.display='none';
    });
});
```

And this works perfectly well. However the previous iteration of this was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#galeria_popup').click(function() {
        $('#light').style.display='block';
        $('#black').style.display='block';
    });

    $('#black_overlay').click(function() {
        $('#light').style.display='none';
        $('#black').style.display='none';
    });
});
```

Which for all I know should work, except I get an `Undefined reference` error in the console.

I understand that JavaScript is asynchronous, and the order by which code is written and called while the DOM loads matters heavily. But this is all inside the `$(document).ready` function, and the `<script>` tags in the end of the `<body>` tag. 
I'm very curious to ***why*** this happens, and why not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [jQuery objects](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), like `$('#light')`/`$('#black')` don't have `style` properties.

You need to access the DOM elements within the [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/):

```
$('#galeria_popup').click(function() {
    $('#light')[0].style.display='block';
    $('#black')[0].style.display='block';
});
```

..or

```
$('#galeria_popup').click(function() {
    $('#light').get(0).style.display='block';
    $('#black').get(0).style.display='block';
});
```

..or just use jQuery methods:

```
$('#galeria_popup').click(function() {
    $('#light, #black').show();
});
```

Comment: So ***everything*** I select with jQuery will be treated as an object and therefore not have the CSS properties available?

Comment: @Digriz Basically anything wrapped in `$()` is a jQuery object. You need to access the DOM elements within the object in order to access certain properties.. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/ Likewise, you can't use jQuery methods on regular DOM elements. You can wrap them with `$()` in order to turn them into jQuery objects though. For example `$(document.getElementById('light'));`

Comment: I guess I'm still pretty green at how jQuery handles things, but I definitely prefer it over vanilla JS most of the times. Cheers!